# How to apply dask method to apply functions on files in list?

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, dask

first of all, thanks for this community and all advice we  can retrieve, it's really appreciate!
This is my first venture into parallel processing and I have been looking into Dask by my own but I am having trouble actually coding it... to be honest I am really lost

In on of my project, I want to trigger URL and retrieve observations data (meteorological station) from xml files.
For each URL, I run some different process in order to: retreive data from URL, parsing XML information to dataframe, apply a filter and store data in MySQL database.
So i need to loop these process over thousands of URL (station)...

I wrote a sequential code , and it take 300s to finish computation which is really to long and not efficient.

As we are applying the same process for each station, I think I can speed-up all the computations, but I don't know where to start. I used delayed from dask but I don't think it's the best approach.

This is my code so far:
First I have some functions.

```
def xml_to_dataframe(ood_xml):
    tmp_file = wget.download(ood_xml)
    prstree = ETree.parse(tmp_file)
    root = prstree.getroot()    
    ################ Section to retrieve data for one station and apply parameter
    all_obs = []  
    for obs in root.iter('observations'):
        ood_observation = []
        for n, param in enumerate(list_parameters):
            x=obs.find(variable_to_check).text
            ood_observation.append(x)    
        all_obs.append(ood_observation)
    return(pd.DataFrame(all_obs, columns=list_parameters))   
        
def filter_criteria(df,threshold,criteria):   
    if criteria in df.columns:
        result = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if pd.to_numeric(row[criteria],errors='coerce') >= threshold:
                result.append(index)    
        return result   
    else:
        #print(criteria + ' parameter does not exist for this station !!! ')
        return([])  
  
def get_and_filter_data(filename,criteria,threshold):
    try:
        xmlToDf = xml_to_dataframe(filename)
        final_df = xmlToDf.loc[filter_criteria(xmlToDf,threshold,criteria)]
        some msql connection and instructions....
    except:
        pass
```

and then the main code I want to parallelise:

```
criteria = 'temperature'
threshold = 22   
filenames =[url1.html, url2.html, url3.html]

for file in filenames:
    get_and_filter_data(file,criteria,threshold)
```

Do you have any advice to do it ?

Many thanks for your help !

Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this is what you are after, but one way is via `delayed`:

```py
from dask import delayed, compute

delayeds = [delayed(get_and_filter_data)(file,criteria,threshold) for file in filenames]
results = compute(delayeds)
```